# Can websites force app downloads?

Tags: ios, safari

I clicked on a link on a website for developers and obviously the dev site had been taken over by scammers but I didn’t know at the time I clicked.

When I clicked the website redirected a few times before I got chance to close it. A pop up came up and an Apple notification saying do I want to restore Apple Music app with options OK or Cancel. Safari was frozen when I couldn’t do anything on iPhone other than close phone with the side button or answer the notification.

So I press Cancel and closed the website.

I cleared Safari history and data and turned phone on and off again.

I have not noticed anything strange. I have checked apps on iPhone and nothing seems to have happened.

But what is the intention of this?

Would it have installed just the music app, or did it install something even tho' I canceled?

How do we know if anything did happen or if access has been gained?

And how do we protect against this?

Forcing apps to open or install it’s a pretty big issue..

iPhone iOS - 16.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like you did mostly did the right things, however I wouldn't have clicked either 'Cancel' or 'OK', but simply force quit Safari and rebooted the phone.

iOS **does** protect you from actual manipulation of apps. I believe the message was fake and even clicking 'OK' would not have initiated anything without asking for authentication, after which it may have attempted some other type of malware or virus installation.